# Is it possible to automatically configure GPO on multiple systems?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm responsible for managing incoming computers at work and I was wondering if there was a program or way to quickly change Group Policy settings without having to manually change each and every setting by hand. The version of Windows ranges from XP to 8.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you're not using a Windows domain?

Comment: No. I wish I were though. That would make my life  much easier.

Comment: As suggested in my answer, setting up a domain server is the best/easiest method in the end.

Comment: The blog post [Utilities for automating Local Group Policy management](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2008/05/07/lgpo-utilities.aspx) mentions a few tools that might be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a [Windows Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server) and use [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) with a [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) for your network.

This will allow you to use and control group policies, users, security, etc. centrally by using tools like the Group Policy Management, and Active Directory Users & Computers consoles.  Any policies set in this environment will automatically update the workstations regularly.

If you are not willing, or cannot, use a proper Windows Server and domain, then your best bet may be to determine which policies you want to set, [look up the registry settings the GP's actually set](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25250) (most GP settings work that way), and then create a batch file that utilizes a list of computers/IP's, a loop, and  [`Reg.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx) (or alike) to modify the registry on the remote computers.

Or possibly make the batch file that works for one/any computer (generically), locate that batch file on a share someplace, and then add the batch file's network path to the start-up of each computer.

Doing it either way should enable you to only have to edit it in one spot if you wish to make changes, and those changes should take effect on the next start-up of the computers.